# How to get a list of users in the client code, but keep the users ids private

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, facebook-graph-api

I'm very new to Nodejs and I'm trying to develop an app in Nodejs with Facebook authentication and I need to let the user (after he/she is logged in with Facebook) choose some of his Facebook friends by clicking on some control. I'm dynamically creating divs after importing the user's friends from the server. How do I make sure that a specific div represents a unique person, so that I can collect his identity back when the user clicks on it? My first idea was to use the Facebook ID, and save it in a hidden input, but I realized later it might not be secure? Is it? What is the best approach to this from a security point of view?

Comment: Is a Facebook ID private in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook ID's are public as stated in [Facebook documentation](https://www.facebook.com/help/211813265517027) so you can use them without security concern.

Comment: Thank you so much! That should have been my question :)